# MySQL Case Function combine with NOT IN Function

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE tree (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `p_id` VARCHAR(4)
);

INSERT INTO tree
  (`id`, `p_id`)
VALUES
  ('1', null),
  ('2', '1'),
  ('3', '1'),
  ('4', '2'),
  ('5', '2');

CREATE TABLE Result (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `Type` VARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO Result
  (`id`, `Type`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Root'),
  ('2', 'Inner'),
  ('3', 'Leaf'),
  ('4', 'Leaf'),
  ('5', 'Leaf');

SELECT
    id
    ,CASE
        WHEN p_id is NULL THEN 'Root'
        WHEN id IN (
                    SELECT p_id 
                    FROM tree) 
        THEN 'INNER'
        WHEN id NOT IN(
                       SELECT p_id
                       FROM tree)
        THEN 'LEAF'
        END AS Type
FROM tree
```

Return

```
id  Type                                                                                            
1   Root                                                                                                             
2   INNER                                                                                                    
3   null                                                                                          
4   null                                                                                          
5   null
```

Prefere Return

```
1   Root                                                                                                             
2   INNER                                                                                                    
3   LEAF                                                                                          
4   LEAF                                                                                          
5   LEAF
```

and also can i get any suggestion which function can be use with case function in MySQL Function

Comment: SELECT
 id
 ,CASE
     WHEN p_id is NULL THEN 'Root'
        WHEN id IN (
             SELECT p_id 
             FROM tree) 
        THEN 'INNER'
        # WHEN id NOT IN(
        #         SELECT p_id
        #         FROM tree)
        # THEN 'LEAF'
        ELSE 'lEAF'
        END AS Type
FROM tree <this will give the answer i want but is there any other way similar i use the function NOT IN with the case function>

Comment: i already set up template test platform, you can take a look at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bv7cf7TdJs71aTsjsgHorp/0

Comment: Why is `p_id` `VARCHAR` instead of `INTEGER`?

Comment: What does the `Result` table have to do with this question?

Comment: p_id is parent_id , might be sting type in later that is why set in varchar, the result is the desire table for testing case

Answer (score 3):

here  is how you can do it :

```
select distinct t.*,case when t.p_id is null then 'root' 
                         when p.p_id is null then 'leaf' 
                         else 'inner' 
                    end as type
from tree t 
left join tree p on p.p_id = t.id
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=551d00e935505353e47d42527ebf07c1)*

Answer (score 2):

Change the `NOT IN` subquery to filter out `p_id = NULL`, because when you compare with that you get `NULL`.

```
SELECT
    id
    ,CASE
        WHEN p_id is NULL THEN 'Root'
        WHEN id IN (
                    SELECT p_id 
                    FROM tree) 
        THEN 'INNER'
        WHEN id NOT IN (
                    SELECT p_id 
                    FROM tree
                    WHERE p_id IS NOT NULL) 
        THEN 'LEAF'
        END AS Type
FROM tree
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kQQ9uWhb8Mzyt4LhfUXaJe/0)

However, I actually recommend you use the `LEFT JOIN` method in @eshirvana's answer.